# Value of type 'Self.ManageableType' has no member 'uid'

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, nsmanagedobject

This is my code, which builds in XCode 7.2.1.
When I try to build the project in XCode 7.3 beta 2, I got the error "Value of type 'Self.ManageableType' has no member 'uid'"

```
protocol Manageable {
  typealias ManageableType : NSManagedObject
  var uid: String { get set }
}

extension Manageable {

  static func className() -> String {
    return String(self)
  }

  static func fetchObjects(predicate: NSPredicate?,
    completion:(fetchedObjects: [String: ManageableType]) -> ()) {
      let entityDescription = NSEntityDescription.entityForName(className(),
        inManagedObjectContext: CoreDataStack.sharedInstance.context)
      let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest()
      fetchRequest.entity = entityDescription
      if let p = predicate {
        fetchRequest.predicate = p
      }
      var fetchedObjectsDict: [String: ManageableType] = [:]
      do {
        let result = try CoreDataStack.sharedInstance.context.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest) as! [ManageableType]
        if result.count > 0 {
          for object in result {
            fetchedObjectsDict[object.uid] = object
          }
        }
      } catch {
        print("ERROR FETCH MANAGEABLE OBJECTS: \(error)")
      }
      completion(fetchedObjects: fetchedObjectsDict)
  }
}
```

When I try to change loop code block into:

```
for object in result {
    let uid = object.valueForKey("uid") as! String
    fetchedObjectsDict[uid] = object
}
```

I got the error "Ambiguous use of 'valueForKey'"

Why these errors happen here in new XCode version, help please?

Comment: Apart from your problem the check `if result.count > 0` is redundant. If `result` is empty the repeat loop is skipped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your protocol extension needs a type constraint

```
extension Manageable where Self : NSManagedObject, ManageableType == Self { ... }
```